# How programmatically filter text?

Tags: 7, entities, input-formats

I need to display a text and apply the chosen filter to it. The text is saved using the `text_format` field type.

So I know the original text, I know the chosen format type but I don't know how to actually filter the text.

How can I programmatically filter text? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically. If yes,  have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959962/how-do-i-programmatically-apply-a-drupal-input-filter

Comment: it was a bad day today. I used this so many times before but I just couldn't remember now. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The answer is to short. It got converted to comment automatically :-(. You can still upvote the comment ;-).

Comment: @BetaRide if you add a link to `check_markup()`, and also copy the summary description, you'll have a perfectly acceptable (even _good_) answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959962/how-do-i-programmatically-apply-a-drupal-input-filter) describes how to do this programmatically.

Just call [check_markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959962/how-do-i-programmatically-apply-a-drupal-input-filter) and pass in your text and the filter id.

```
check_markup($text, $format_id = NULL, $langcode = '', $cache = FALSE)
```

> Run all the enabled filters on a piece of text.

Comment: There is a difference between *filter_id* and *format_id*. `check_markup()` accepts a *format_id*, and will run all filters applied to that format.

Answer (score 4):

With `check_markup()` function you are forced to use text format (text format = banch of filters).

If you want to use only **ONE**, exact filter without full filter format (like: *Convert line breaks into HTML*) then use this custom function.

```
/**
 * Custom function to use only ONE filter wightout full format.
 *
 * @param {string} $string String to filter.
 * @param {string} $filter Filter name to use on $string
 * @return {string}        Filtered string.
 */
function filter($string, $filter) {
  $filters = filter_get_filters();
  $filter_autop = $filters[$filter];

  return $filter_autop['process callback']($string);
}
```

You can check list of available filters with `dpm(filter_get_filters())`.

Comment: This is a correct answer!

Comment: This may work for some filters, but only the simple ones.  In general the process callback https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/callback_filter_process/7.x takes more parameters, including filter settings.  There is also a prepare callback.